# Why an href link is not redirecting to the proper target?

Tags: html, asp.net, web

I have been trying to print a sample page in the browser by following the updated instructions, but it doesn't work or make sense.

[Link to GitHub code](https://github.com/solyarisoftware/posprinterdriver)

It says:

Print from your web page (user action).

You can print from web doing a link in your HTML page:

Print from a web page visualized in an Android device web browser. Just embed in your page a link or a button:

```
a href="com.fidelier.printfromweb://$biguhw$Print From Web$intro$$small$Print small letter$intro$->$intro$->$intro$->$intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$$cut$$intro$"Test print from web/a
```

It doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put "< and >" so it would be:

```
<a href="com.fidelier.printfromweb://$biguhw$Print From Web$intro$$small$Print small letter$intro$->$intro$->$intro$->$intro$$intro$$intro$$intro$$cut$$intro$"Test print from web</a>
```